# How to store formatted text in a database which will be rendered with both ReactJS and React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, content-management-system, wysiwyg

Let's presume there are 4 parts to this problem:

1. A UI which contains a WYSIWYG editor (text formatting, no images)
2. Database to store the content from the WYSIWYG editor
3. A ReactJS FE which renders the content with HTML and CSS
4. A React Native FE which renders the content using RN components and styles

Q1. In what format should I store the content in the database? One example I could think of would be Markdown.

Q2. Following that, what's the best way to render the UI from that data format?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be having a CMS(Content management system), which controls your content, and an independent Nodejs server that can serve it to you so you only have to set up the CMS in one place. If it would be rendering HTML or something similar I'm not too sure. But this seems like the approach for normal text/content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So we already have a CMS. My question was more around suggestions for the format in which to store the text so that it can easily be rendered to both ReactJS and React Native.